# I am getting this error message when I try to connect SQL Server using visual c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ssl

I am making a simple application which is to connect remote SQL Server.

This is the connection string.

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=ip address;Initial Catalog=TELMAR;User ID=sa;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=false;encrypt=false";
```

If I set encrypt to true. I got this error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

If I set encrypt to false. I got this error:

> Cannot open database "TELMAR" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'sa'.

When I tried to connect to the server using SQL Server Management Studio, I could connect without any problem.

I do not know why I cannot connect to SQL Server using Visual C#.

I also enabled TCP\IP and named pipe on both my computer and server.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try adding `TrustServerCertificate=True,` in your connection string and leave `encrypt=true`

Comment: Yeah I tried it as well. when its set to true, same error which is "Cannot open database "TELMAR" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'sa'."

Comment: Change `Trusted_Connection=false` to `Trusted_Connection=true`?

Comment: Follow these [instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/300261/EN-US) to create a Data Link File that you can use to connect to your DB, then open it to get the connection string.

Comment: In SSMS are you connecting as sa with that password?  Have you validated that password?  Does the database accept password authentication?

Comment: @juharr I followed the instruction for data link file and changed to OLEDB from sqlclient. then it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the connection string to this format

```
<add name="TELMAR" connectionString="Data Source = ip adress;Initial Catalog=TELMAR;MultipleActiveResultSets=true; User Id = sa; Password = password providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

And in the program.cs you can initiate the connection string by this way

```
string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TELMAR"].ConnectionString;
```